# Openshift monitoring in Spring, 403 Forbidden error

Tags: java, api, spring-boot, openshift, http-status-code-403

I have Exception like this :

Idea:

> Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path
>   [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 403
>   Forbidden] with root cause
>
> org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 403 Forbidden

Browser statment

Fri Feb 02 08:34:11 CET 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
403 Forbidden

I want to get list of pods from openshift.

My code:

```
    @GetMapping("getPods")
    public List<Pod> podsUpdate(){
        HttpHeaders headres = new HttpHeaders();
        headres.set("Authorization","Bearer <token>");
        RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
        JsonObjectPods jsonObjectPods = null;

        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
                new X509TrustManager() {
                    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        return new X509Certificate[0];
                    }
                    public void checkClientTrusted(
                            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                    }
                    public void checkServerTrusted(
                            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                    }
                }
        };

// Install the all-trusting trust manager
        try {
            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) { }
// Now you can access an https URL without having the certificate in the truststore

            jsonObjectPods = template.getForObject("https://<openshift_address>/api/v1/pods", JsonObjectPods.class, headres);
```

Comment: what token are you using?

Comment: I retrive token from my openshift (window in upper-right corner - "copy login command")